# Minimal example of dragging a QLabel image to desktop

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a Qlabel that is draggable outside of the main widget but all my attempts fail to drag it to the file explorer path and save it as image. Is there any third party documentation that allow that functionality?

My last attempt is as follows:

```
class DraggableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,image):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self)
        self.setPixmap(image)    
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtGui.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & QtGui.Qt.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QtWidgets.QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimedata.setImageData(self.pixmap().toImage())

        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec_(QtGui.Qt.CopyAction | QtGui.Qt.MoveAction)
        
        source = drag.source()
        print("source = %s" % source)
        target = drag.target()   # how to return this target as file explorer path ?
        print("target = %s" % target)
```

Comment: Asking for recommendations regarding third-party documentation is [off-topic on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please therefore edit your question and explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve, and also show your attempted solution.

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless you are using a custom file explorer that you have programmed to work this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`target()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#target) of QDrag only works for objects that are part of the application (in fact, it returns a QObject type, meaning that only *internal* Qt types can be retrieved). This means that you cannot know anything about drops on *external* targets.

The only Qt (and cross-platform compliant) possible solution is to create a temporary file on which the image is saved, and use [`setUrls()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#setUrls) with a single-item list that contains the temporary file path.

The only (and unavoidable) caveat of this approach is that you cannot set the target file name: the file name is internally decided by Qt, and the only possible customization is based on a template file name that will result in some "random" letters and numbers used instead of the `XXXXXX` placeholder.

```py
class DraggableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__(pixmap=image)
        self.tempFiles = []
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().aboutToQuit.connect(
            self.deleteTemporaryFiles)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QtWidgets.QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimedata.setImageData(self.pixmap().toImage())

        tempFile = QtCore.QTemporaryFile(
            QtCore.QDir.tempPath()
            + QtCore.QDir.separator()
            + 'exportXXXXXX.png')
        # temporary files are removed upon their destruction, since the copy
        # or move operations can take an undefined amount of time, we need to
        # keep a reference and eventually destroy them after a reasonable
        # amount of time
        self.tempFiles.append(tempFile)

        self.pixmap().save(tempFile)
        mimedata.setUrls([QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(tempFile.fileName())])

        drag.setPixmap(self.pixmap().scaled(64, 64, 
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

        # an arbitrary amount of time for the removal of the temporary file
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(30000, self.deleteTemporaryFiles)

    def deleteTemporaryFiles(self):
        while self.tempFiles:
            self.tempFiles.pop().deleteLater()
```

Finally, an *extremely* important note: considering that the drag operation is completely based on temporary files, this can represent a *serious* issue whenever the file is dropped on a program that supports direct file dragging from the file manager and doesn't properly manage the access to that file: since the code above deletes the temporary file(s) for performance/safety/security reasons, that source file can become invalid. If the target program accepts a drop from your application, it is possible that the program won't be able to access it whenever the `deleteTemporaryFiles` gets called and the result is completely unexpected. That program could crash, *your* program could crash, or you might even get a *total* system crash.
While the provided code *does* work, you **must** be aware of this aspect, and eventually warn the user about its usage.

Comment: it's almost working except windows pops up with the error message saying "This action can't be complete beacause this file is open in Python" when i drag and drop image ouside of widget to folder.

Comment: Try adding `tempFile.close()` after saving the pixmap and *before* the drag exec.

Comment: i didn't solve it, but i tried to drag it to another folder that is not related to the C:\\ dir and it saved successfully i guess it only fails to save to C:\\ paths, i don't why but thanks man for the help <3

Comment: actually it is not about C:\\ dirs it's about the partition i'm running the python file from, if i moved the files to parition D:\\ for example draging to this parititon is denyed always :"/

Comment: @Ahmed4end Sorry, I read again the documentation about QTemporaryFile and I realized I misunderstood the creation of its path. See the updated code (the line starting with `tempFile = ...`), it should work now.

Comment: same problem accures but i tried to remove `QtCore.Qt.MoveAction` and only leave `QtCore.Qt.CopyAction` alone as arguement and it worked i can drag and drop image to same parition without any error, idk why exactly but i believe there is a reason.

Comment: if you have an explination it would be great to hear

Comment: @Ahmed4end Is it the *same* error? Does it happen even with keeping `MoveAction` *and* calling `tempFile.close()` as said above? Sorry, but I cannot test it on Windows, so I have to "guess" a bit, since the Linux behavior is different.

Comment: it is the same error when keeping `MoveAction `

Comment: @Ahmed4end please answer *both* questions.

Comment: still same error even with `tempFile.close()` and `MoveAction ` used

Comment: Ok. As said, I cannot test on Windows, so I have to make some assumptions. First of all, Windows treats files in a different way than *nix systems (includin macOS): for instance, on Linux you can remove a file even if it's still open by some program, the program will be still able to access that file, but no other program will, and it will not be visible in the file system. QTemporaryFile is a bit peculiar class, and as long that object exists for Qt, the file will be "owned" by Qt, so it's possible that in Windows it's not possible to move due to that "ownership", even if the file is closed.

Comment: Since in my code I already handle a "lazy removal" function, I believe it's quite safe to use only the `CopyAction` alone. The only caveat of this is that if the program crashes, the remaining temporary files that have not been removed yet will not be deleted. If you want, you could add a function that, on startup, checks for matching file names in the `tempPath` and asks the user for removal, using [`entryList()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList) with a matching filter: `QDir(QDir.tempPath()).entryList(['export??????.png']))`.

Comment: @Ahmed4end I added a further important note. Please read it carefully, as it is *extremely* important.